# Brightness Settings on my HP laptop do not work on Debian 11 (Bullseye)

Tags: gnu-screen, brightness

Hi good day everyone I have an HP 15-n220ca laptop computer on my Debian 11 Bullseye operating system running LXQt, and I am having trouble to turn down the brightness on my laptop screen. It is all the way to the maximum and I want it at 50% (half) of the brightness. I tried using the brightness keys on the top of my keyboard that are the F2 and the f3 buttons, and that doesn't work; It brings up the monitor settings, which does nothing.

I even tried to alter the open box file adding this code,

brightnessctl set 6.25%+
  
  
      brightnessctl set 6.25%-

To the home folder my username openbox, there is one foul in there called lxqt-rc.xml

So I added it and put that just before the  word. Still doesn't work.

I tried to install Xbox light and typed into terminal

xbacklight -set 50

And this also did not help.

I'm now lost that I don't know how to get the brightness down. It is too high and it's hurting my eyes when I look at the screen for long periods.

Also I'm trying to install or to change the settings of blue light and I can't seem to have the blue light off or the settings turn down 24 hours 7 days a week. Red shift doesn't work for this as it only sends it for night time but it doesn't give me the option to change any settings.

So please these two things I need help with and I really would appreciate it. If you need more information I can provide you somehow with it, but I'm a very new beginner at this operating system. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Click on power Power Settings. Right lower corner next to the clock. Brightness is there.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, also with an HP, and this worked for me:

`brightnessctl s 50%`

I used the command line, not the open box file. Also, when you want to increase brightness, the plus sign has to precede the value:

`brightnessctl s +50%`

while the minus sign goes after:

`brightnessctl s 50%-`

Hope this helps!

P.S. Power Settings affect only the brightness level at inactivity, which does not apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package liblxqt-backlight-helper, then `brightnessctl` should work.